# Pull - to - refresh doesn't work with multiple Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

Im trying to implement one refresher to tableView and scrollView on one ViewController. When there are no data - hide table view and show scrollView. Is it possible to implement one refresher so I don't need to write two?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var allScreenView: UIView!

var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Update")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

    // Adding pull to request to scrollview
    scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)

    // Adding pull to reqest to tableView
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

@objc func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {

    // End refreshing after 1 second
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
        self?.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
}
```

When I implement to both, it doesn't refresh

Comment: please share your code which fetchs data from somewhere. I mean what is your data source of `tableView` and `scrollView`. You should add fetch lines into `@objc func refresh(sender:)` block and then you should `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: it doesn't matter, even with this code if you comment line with tableView.addSubview(refreshControl) it will work

Comment: @Serj are you using tableview inside scrollview ?

Comment: No, the scrollView is just on TableView (in work case if there is data in tableView the scrollView.isHidden = true)

Comment: Try using the two different instances of refreshcontroller, may be it should work

Comment: Yes, I know it will work, but can I use just one

Comment: You can use one selector. But having a single reference and adding it to two different views is not an appropriate method.